# Make a phone call programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, telephony, phone-call

How can I make a phone call programmatically on iPhone? I tried the following code but nothing happened:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = mymobileNO.titleLabel.text;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Comment: For code in swift you can follow this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29869456/3950397

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Probably the *mymobileNO.titleLabel.text* value doesn't include the scheme **//**

Your code should look like this:

**ObjectiveC**

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

**Swift**

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(mymobileNO.titleLabel.text))") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: There's no chance we could go back to original application with this approach.

Comment: I think Mellon's approach is better as it prompts the user first, and then returns to your app after the call. Just make sure to use canOpenURL: and fallback to the tel: prompt since telprompt is not official and could be removed in a future iOS version.

Comment: How can I make phone call from apple watch.

Comment: Can I turn on speaker programmatically for call originated this way in ios?

Comment: even **tel:1234567890** also works just like how **tell://1234567890** it works

Answer (score 218):

To go back to original app you can use telprompt:// instead of tel:// - The tell prompt will prompt the user first, but when the call is finished it will go back to your app:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Comment: I have a question: will the apps that use telprompt:// be rejected by Apple?

Comment: I know this is old but I did find a couple people claiming their apps were approved using telprompt: 
"I've submited my app that uses telprompt with shared application without the uiwebkit and has been successfully approved by apple.
answered January 19, 2013

Pablo Alejandro Junge"

Comment: telprompt:// is undocumented and should therefore never be relied upon. Things may changed, For example Apple could decide a given URL scheme is something they need exclusively or simply do not wish to allow, then your app will break.

Comment: @DevC: Then what is alternative to have phone call feature in our app?

Comment: @BaSha use `tel://` not `telprompt://`

Comment: without backslash also works..i.e we can use **tel:** and **telprompt:**

Answer (score 25):

Merging the answers of @Cristian Radu and @Craig Mellon, and the comment from @joel.d, you should do:

```
NSURL *urlOption1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:phone]];
NSURL *urlOption2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:phone]];
NSURL *targetURL = nil;

if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:urlOption1]) {
    targetURL = urlOption1;
} else if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:urlOption2]) {
    targetURL = urlOption2;
}

if (targetURL) {
    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:targetURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:targetURL];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
}
```

This will first try to use the "telprompt://" URL, and if that fails, it will use the "tel://" URL. If both fails, you're trying to place a phone call on an iPad or iPod Touch.

Swift Version :

```
let phone = mymobileNO.titleLabel.text
let phoneUrl = URL(string: "telprompt://\(phone)"
let phoneFallbackUrl = URL(string: "tel://\(phone)"
if(phoneUrl != nil && UIApplication.shared.canOpenUrl(phoneUrl!)) {
  UIApplication.shared.open(phoneUrl!, options:[String:Any]()) { (success) in
    if(!success) {
      // Show an error message: Failed opening the url
    }
  }
} else if(phoneFallbackUrl != nil && UIApplication.shared.canOpenUrl(phoneFallbackUrl!)) {
  UIApplication.shared.open(phoneFallbackUrl!, options:[String:Any]()) { (success) in
    if(!success) {
      // Show an error message: Failed opening the url
    }
  }
} else {
    // Show an error message: Your device can not do phone calls.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The answers here are perfectly working. I am just converting Craig Mellon answer to Swift. If someone comes looking for swift answer, this will help them.

```
 var phoneNumber: String = "telprompt://".stringByAppendingString(titleLabel.text!) // titleLabel.text has the phone number.
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:phoneNumber)!)
```

Comment: you can also use tel:// in place of telprompt://

Comment: let phoneNumber: String = "telprompt://\(titleLabel.text)"                 UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:phoneNumber)!)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Xamarin to develop an iOS application, here is the C# equivalent to make a phone call within your application:

```
string phoneNumber = "1231231234";
NSUrl url = new NSUrl(string.Format(@"telprompt://{0}", phoneNumber));
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
let phoneNumber: String = "tel://3124235234"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: phoneNumber)!)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3.0,

```
static func callToNumber(number:String) {

        let phoneFallback = "telprompt://\(number)"
        let fallbackURl = URL(string:phoneFallback)!

        let phone = "tel://\(number)"
        let url = URL(string:phone)!

        let shared = UIApplication.shared

        if(shared.canOpenURL(fallbackURl)){
            shared.openURL(fallbackURl)
        }else if (shared.canOpenURL(url)){
            shared.openURL(url)
        }else{
            print("unable to open url for call")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The Java RoboVM equivalent:

```
public void dial(String number)
{
  NSURL url = new NSURL("tel://" + number);
  UIApplication.getSharedApplication().openURL(url);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried the Swift 3 option above, but it didnt work. I think you need the following if you are to run against iOS 10+ on Swift 3:

**Swift 3 (iOS 10+):**

```
let phoneNumber = mymobileNO.titleLabel.text       
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: phoneNumber)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(number)"), 
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let phone = "tel://\("1234567890")";
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone)!;
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead

in Objective-c iOS 10+ use :

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use openurl.

For making a call in swift 5.1, just use the following code: (I have tested it in Xcode 11)

```
let phone = "1234567890"
if let callUrl = URL(string: "tel://\(phone)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(callUrl) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(callUrl)
}
```

Edit: For Xcode 12.4, swift 5.3, just use the following:

`UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "tel://555-123-1234")! as URL)`

### Make sure that you import UIKit, or it will say that it cannot find UIApplication in scope.