# Initiate phone calls without confirmation dialog like 1-2-Contact

Tags: ios, ios4

Some time ago, I wrote a small app, which needs to create outbound phone calls on iOS. I used an URL to prepare the call like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929717/how-can-i-make-a-phone-call-programmatically-on-iphone).

Since I never found an iOS method to perform the call - **without a 'Would you like to call...' confirmation dialog** - I finally dropped the project.

Recently I found 1-2-Contact, which does just this: If I press the phone icon, the phone call gets established without a confirmation dialog.

Does 1-2-Contact use a private frameworks? **Or does a 'initiate phone call' method exist?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"9123123"; //your number

NSString *telString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telString]];
```

Works for me.

Edit 1:

```
NSString *dtmfAfterPickup=@"0";

NSString *telString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@,%@", phoneNumber, dtmfAfterPickup];
```

Comment: That what's since the other link question. And it's what I do. You don't see the confirmation dialog?

Comment: No, it stars the call automatically. =/ Humm.. add this (see edit)

Comment: Thx again. Works. Don't know, why it didn't work before. Probably a noter iOS release. Too bad.