# How Can I open phone's keypad from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

From my app I want to open the phone's dialer keypad which is used to make phone call. I tried as

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:"]];
```

But it does not open the keypad of phone.

Comment: Do you want to just open a phone style keypad? or do you want to automatically initiate a phone call after the user types the number in?

Comment: @gamozzii none of them, I want to open the dialer which is used to type number and make call by default in iphone.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to open the Phone's keypad. You can design your own phone pad in your view controller, add DTMF Tones for sounds and make it look like a phone's keypad.
If you want your own phonepad and want to have it within your app then this is the only way.

It is possible to open the Phone app and execute a call if you want,refer to the link below to know how its done.

[Make a phone call programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929717/how-can-i-make-a-phone-call-programmatically-on-iphone)

Answer (score -1):

You can use it by setting a property in UITextField keyboardtype .

```
selectedTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
```

Comment: @daniel Actually there is no textfield in my view. I want to open the default dialer application of iphone. thanks.