# How open phone keypad iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I open keypad native from iOS in my app. I try with UITextField

```
[textField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypePhonePad];
```

But no is good solution.

Comment: What do you mean that you solution is no good? What is wrong with it?

Comment: I need open phone Keypad dial in my app, how? if implement in textfield no show native phone keypad from my iphone.

Comment: Why do you want the "native" phone keypad? What's your goal? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant how to show the keyboard for the textField without the user touching it, try

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder]
```

Comment: I need open phone Keypad dial in my app, how? if implement in textfield no show native phone keypad from my iphone. Not show keyboard from textfield

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896173/how-can-i-open-phones-keypad-from-my-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896173/how-can-i-open-phones-keypad-from-my-app)