# Launch phone calls and show a call screen from guided access?

Tags: ios, ios7, accessibility, guided-access

I have a "home screen-replacement" app on Android for people with eyesight problems and I'm considering making a similar App for iOS.

Since home screen replacements don't exist in iOS, I'm thinking of optimizing my app for "guided access" or "single app" mode. That way someone can set the phone up from a senior, and he can call his favorite contacts and receive calls on a more controlled and simpler enviroment.

The problem is that I don't know whether it's possible now how to do this. Can calls be launched and answered from guided access? If not any ideas on how to do it will be appreciated

Comment: In what way do you make this screen better than Voice Over in iOS?

Comment: In that my grandad will be able to use it.

Comment: I understand. But, do you intend to have a spare iPhone with this screen up and guided access turned on, so that its super easy for your branded to use it? Or, do you intend to have it like any other app on iPhone? (I don't know how home screen replacements on Android are more helpful than Voice Over for vision impaired users)

Comment: I intend to have a spare iPhone with this app locked in guided access. In some cases voice over isn't enough, some people can have 4 icons on screen at a time top because they cannot differenciate more. But they are still eager to do calculations, call relatives or take photos.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible with current APIs. Guided Access will prevent users from switching away to another app, including Phone. Similarly, incoming calls will be missed silently.

**Edit:** You could, of course, implement your own call feature over VOIP, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: Thanks, and what about building my own call screen, so users don't have to leave the APP? I'm not sure if "call-screen-replacements" exist in iOS

Comment: They don't. You cannot stand in for system apps. As I wrote in my edit, you would need to reimplement calling, yourself. Instead, consider using system accessibility features, alone. You can increase font legibility, increase font sizes, and restrict your grandfather to the "Favorites" tab of the Phone app.

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you, to make phone calls using existing API:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"tel://911";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

mere about calls here [How can I make a phone call programmatically on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929717/1403732)

Comment: do you know what would happen if run in an app in guided access?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, just tried it.  You're completely sandboxed in Guided Access.