# How to use openURL for making a phone call in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsurl, xcode6, openurl

I have converted the code for making a phone call from Objective-C to Swift, but in Objective-C, we can set the type of the URL that we like to open (e.g. telephone, SMS, web) like this:

```
@"tel:xx"
@"mailto:info@example.es"
@"http://stackoverflow.com"
@"sms:768number"
```

The code in Swift is:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "9809088798")
```

I read that have not released any scheme parameter for `tel:`, but I don't know if Swift can detect if the string is for making a phone call, sending email, or opening a website. Or may I write:

```
(string : "tel//:9809088798")
```

?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Did you try it? Did it work? And please do not delete and repost questions.

Comment: My problem is that I want know if this is correct for call:  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "9809088798") Because have only the emulator for try it

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I am pretty sure you want:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://9809088798")!)
```

(note that in your question text, you put `tel//:`, not `tel://`).

NSURL's string init expects a well-formed URL.  It will not turn a bunch of numbers into a telephone number.  You sometimes see phone-number detection in UIWebView, but that's being done at a higher level than NSURL.

EDIT: Added ! per comment below

Comment: Just a tiny correction UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://9809088798")!) you need to use the ! after the NSURL because it returns an optional.

Comment: this will directly start calling on the number (ofcourse after 10.3 iOS will ask permission to call) but what if I need to open the iPhone dialer with filled a number ?? Can I achieve this?

Comment: Awesome Answer sir :)

Answer (score 19):

A self-contained solution in **Swift**:

```
private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
  if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
      application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you should be able to use `callNumber("7178881234")` to make a call.

Comment: The problem is that your solution does not return to the app after the phone call has been finished on iOS7.

Comment: Hm, curious if there is a solution that does do that.. might be a restriction on iOS.

Answer (score 8):

For Swift in iOS:

```
var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "tel://9809088798")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

Comment: this will directly start calling on the number (ofcourse after 10.3 iOS will ask permission to call) but what if I need to open the iPhone dialer with filled a number ?? Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to remember to remove the whitespaces or it won't work:

```
if let telephoneURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(phoneNumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: ""))") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(telelphoneURL)
    }
```

"telprompt://" will prompt the user to call or cancel while "tel://" will call directly.

Answer (score 6):

@  confile:

> The problem is that your solution does not return to the app after the
>   phone call has been finished on iOS7. –  Jun 19 at 13:50

&@ Zorayr

> Hm, curious if there is a solution that does do that.. might be a
>   restriction on iOS.

use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://9809088798")!)
```

You will get a prompt to Call/Cancel but it returns to your application. AFAIK there is no way to return (without prompting)

Answer (score 5):

You must insert "+"\ is another way

```
private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
  if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"tel://"+"\(phoneNumber)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
      application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Small update to Swift 3

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://9809088798")! as URL)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet can tell if the SIM is there or not and if the device is capable of making the call and if ok then it'll make the call

```
  var info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    var carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider
    if carrier != nil && carrier.mobileNetworkCode == nil || carrier.mobileNetworkCode.isEqual("") {
       //SIM is not there in the phone
    }
    else if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canopenURL(NSURL(string: "tel://9809088798")!)
    {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://9809088798")!)
    }
    else    
    {
      //Device does not have call making capability  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For making a call in swift 5.1, just use the following code: (I have tested it in Xcode 11)

```
let phone = "1234567890"
if let callUrl = URL(string: "tel://\(phone)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(callUrl) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(callUrl)
}
```

Edit:
For Xcode 12.4, swift 5.3, just use the following:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "tel://555-123-1234")! as URL)
```

## Make sure that you import UIKit, or it will say that it cannot find UIApplication in scope.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3

```
if let phoneCallURL:URL = URL(string:"tel://\(phoneNumber ?? "")") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4:

```
func call(phoneNumber: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: phoneNumber) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                                        (success) in
                                        print("Open \(phoneNumber): \(success)")
            })
        } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            print("Open \(phoneNumber): \(success)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use the function:

```
let phoneNumber = "tel://+132342424"
call(phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 and above**

```
let dialer = URL(string: "tel://5028493750")
    if let dialerURL = dialer {
        UIApplication.shared.open(dialerURL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer deferring the URL creation to the built-ins like:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "tel"
components.path = "1234567890"
print(components.url!) //Prints out: "tel:1234567890"
```

Which can then be used in `UIApplication.shared.openURL`