# click on a label in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, call

I want to make the label that on click on it to make call to number. I know that iOS has this option, but how can I do it in Swift?

I found just how to do it in ObjC:

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:2135554321"]];
}
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use openURL for a phone call with swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251259/how-to-use-openurl-for-a-phone-call-with-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://2135554321"))
```

**example**

```
if let  CallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"tel://\(yourMobileNUmber)") {
let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
if (application.canOpenURL( CallURL)) {
  application.openURL( CallURL);
  }
else
 {
   // your number not valid
   let tapAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!!!", message: "Your mobile number is invalid", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
tapAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
 self.presentViewController(tapAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
 }
```

**Type-2**

```
  // add gesture to your Label
 var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
 yourLabelName.userInteractionEnabled=true
 yourLabelName.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

// handle the function of UILabel
func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
     if let  CallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"tel://\(yourMobileNUmber)") {
let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
if (application.canOpenURL( CallURL)) {
  application.openURL( CallURL);
  }
 else
 {
   // your number not valid
   let tapAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!!!", message: "Your mobile number is invalid", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
tapAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
 self.presentViewController(tapAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: can I connect it to label? Label does not have click function. So, how can I realize it?

Comment: check the updated answer bro.., in the lable place use custom UIButton, it is easy to work

Comment: if you need assistance ask me, I hope with you\

Comment: I prefered the second version, but it does not work =/

Comment: what the error u faced, put the break point and check the method is called or not, else part update your question please

Comment: it does not call the function. I think tapGesture does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83091/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-anbu-karthik).