# Call phone number from TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have something like that:

[image]

I want to call a number when I push on the right. I try with `tel//:` but it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use openURL for making a phone call in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251259/how-to-use-openurl-for-making-a-phone-call-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though your syntax `tel//:` is incorrect. Instead, try using `tel://` like the following:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)")!)
```