# URL scheme as to send a request with *...# syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Normally, in  default calling  application of iPhone ,I open number keyboard and pressed `*100*stringnumber# (example *100* 12345678989 #)`, and press call button , it make a request to add money to my sim  card account.

Now, I make an app, that it scan the string number auto by camera, and I want after scan that string, it can send the request to add money like the way in calling application.

I make an URL scheme with string: `"tel:*100*stringnumber#"` and send it to open calling app, but it didn't work, I search and know it just for dialog a phone number.

Is there any way or syntax to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a phone call programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929717/make-a-phone-call-programmatically)

Comment: i tried to understand but could not

Comment: do you want a telephone number validation? so that for invalid number, a call can't start

Comment: it is not a phone number, it is a serial number of prepay phone card, and if i want to use that prepay phone card, i have to press : *100* serial number # and call, nut it not make a call, it make a request and send to exchange to add money for my phone number

Comment: https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t34.0-12/12166987_1716611205227824_1726530100_n.jpg?oh=0841b6093258e3c7134d4a49d914a3a0&oe=56274583