# Phone calls not working ios 9

Tags: objective-c, ios9, phone-call

I have tried with the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phone]];
```

and also registered strings in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, but still not working phone call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a phone call programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929717/make-a-phone-call-programmatically)

Comment: You need to update your question with more details. What is the exact value (including any possible whitespace) of `phone`? Is there any messages in the debug console when you try to call `openURL:`?

Comment: have you check that call facility available or not in your device?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *pho_No = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:1231231234"]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:pho_No])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:pho_No];
}
else
{
    // iPad or iPod Touch, can't make a call
}
```

Also check that, NSURL object must not be nil.