# Show iOS native call UI for outgoing VoIP calls with CallKit

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

When my VoIP app receives a call with CallKit, iOS shows the native system call UI.

How can I show this native call view also for outgoing calls?

Comment: Do you really need to do this using CallKit? Because you can make outgoing calls programmatically by tapping into native phone app now.. see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929717/make-a-phone-call-programmatically

Comment: @ymotov My question is not about how to start a call. I want to see the iOS native call UI whenever there is a call running. Also when started from within the app by dialing or by tapping from the native app.

Comment: I want to start a sip call with my app. Not a normal mobile call.

Comment: got it.. I misunderstood then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not currently a way to immediately show the system's native in-call UI upon dialing an outgoing call from a CallKit VoIP app. However, this native UI is shown if the user locks their device while the VoIP call is ongoing.

Comment: Could one trick the system and show outgoing calls as incoming to the system and show the native call ui this way?

Comment: You would likely hit many issues by trying to do this, since many behaviors and assumptions are made based on whether the call is incoming or outgoing, and a call may not be changed from incoming to outgoing or vice-versa. As always, I would encourage filing a [Bug Report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple to request this capability if it is something you would like!

Comment: @StuartM: So, conclusion is " We can get native system call UI if call is incoming and app is in background". Is that so?

Comment: @NiteshBorad Yes if a CallKit app receives an incoming call while it is in the background, the system's native incoming call UI will be shown.

Comment: Seems a shame we can't use the lovely in-call UI when phone wasn't locked. I guess we should just clone it as closely as possible...

Comment: If the user locks their device while the VoIP call is ongoing, performEndCallAction: will be called then the call ends. The native UI does NOT show as the answer suggested. I am using iOS 10.2.1

Comment: @StuartM : The outgoing call lifecycle mentioned in the document here shows the UI in stages. Do you think its possible to implement?http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/230b83wfxc7m69dm90q/230/230_enhancing_voip_apps_with_callkit.pdf

Comment: Is this still true today in late 2021? We're experiencing this same issue but given the lack of StackOverflow posts on the topic I'm wondering if this has since been resolved.