# Is it possible to create a call tracking app on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, calllog

From all I have read here, creating a call tracking app on iOS seems impossible. However, after some investigation, I have found a couple of workarounds and would like to know if they are legal and would work at all.

So, at least, I will need one of these features:

- access call log history. I've read that's impossible, but also I know that on many devices where iCloud backup is turned on, call history data is saved there, so using some API, for example, [this](https://www.reincubate.com/), I can access it. Am I right?
- receive notifications when the call is ended. I've read this is possible only in foreground, therefore makes no sense. But following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929717/7453375), I see that you can initiate calls from the application, which allows at least to track *outgoing* calls.

Would this be enough or I am wasting time?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're running on a jailbroken device, the answer is no because there is no publicly available API that provides access to the call list and that is a good thing from a privacy point of view.

A quick search shows that CallKit is for integrating VOIP into the call list, so again the answer is no, CallKit will not be of any use to you.

The notifications are there so that your app can respond properly to calls that take place while it is active.