# How can I make a phone call with a button inside a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create contacts app. How can I make a phone call with a button inside a custom `UITableViewCell`?

This is my code. It works only the first time when I press call button. When I `NSLog` it, it gives me a contact number. When I tap on the button, but don't show dialog box.

```
NSString *phoneStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[contactNumbersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]; 

NSLog(@"%@", [contactNumbersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]);

UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: phoneStr] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929717/make-a-phone-call-programmatically

Comment: I tried all ways just at  the first time show dialog box  when I press the 
 cell. for other contacts not work.

Comment: What's the exact value of `phoneStr`?

Comment: Do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question. And that does not tell us the final value at runtime of `phoneStr`. Post the actual value of `phoneStr`. My guess is that it has spaces or other characters that are invalid in a URL.

Comment: You also don't want the // in `tel` uris

Comment: And, are your numbers in the sections, not the rows?

Comment: Yes, Paulw it is in the section

Comment: You still have not posted the actual value for `phoneStr`. What is its value when you call `[NSURL URLWithString: phoneStr]`?

Comment: Its not only one number, for every cell of table view it has different number it's not like SOS or any emergency calling . Are you understand what I say ,sorry for my english is not good.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right , it's contain space I solved it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , as rmaddy said my numbers contain spaces and + so i solved it with this method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27306065/9820328

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
  NSString *phNo = [contactNumbersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",phNo]];

   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
       UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
       [application openURL:phoneUrl options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
   }
```